# Target addresses in Kademlia

Tags: node-discovery, rlpx, p2p

I'm currently trying to understand the Kademlia protocol implemented in Ethereum in order to discover other peers in the network. If I understand these [lines](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/79c90dce200185b6199076ef7ae87f2ad71c3008/p2p/discover/table.go#L298) correctly, a nodes uses both random addresses as well as his own address as *target address*. It then sends this address to its neighbour peers which in turn will return their closest addresses to this *target address*.
Does a node periodically ask their neighbour peers about their closest addresses to his own address? Wouldn't that be wasteful as the answers will not much change over time?

Answer (score 1):

It performs this lookup with its own address as target address only when the table is empty.